# Live site doesn't work

Tags: web8.5

we setup a new publication for our client. This publication is a child of an old publication but with a different language. when we publish the pages to the preview site, they work fine. but when we publish those pages to live site, all pages displayed as 404 page. what's the problem? we use SDL Web 8.5.
The publishing to live site works fine. because we see success status in publish queue.
try 'get-ttmmapping' in powershell, it also returns the correct mapping like this:

```
CmEnvironmentId     : TCMDBUser_OEP6
PublicationId       : tcm:0-461-1
EnvironmentPurpose  : Live
WebApplicationId    : LiveWebsite_RootWebApp
RelativeUrl         : /sea/ma
PrimaryMappedUrl    : https://XXXXXXXX/sea/ma
IsOffline           : False
CdEnvironment       : 
Id                  : Mapping74
ExtensionProperties : {}
```

DXA 1.6

Comment: please provide some more details on your front-end web app : is this using DXA, DD4T or some custom development. Also, it would be useful to check any logs you get in your web application

Comment: Is that published pages are stored in the database or FS?

Comment: It could an issue with the way that your topology is being setup. Refer the below link on using context vs relative URL
https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14247/web-application-vs-web-site-in-topology-manager

Comment: can you tell what's the setup issue? those pages sometimes display well, sometimes show 404 error.