# Add-TtmMapping | Understanding parameter: Relative Url

Tags: content-delivery, sdl-tridion, topology-manager, web8-cu1

I have been trying to add mappings for my websites using below :

```
Add-TtmMapping -Id MAPPINGID -CmEnvironmentId CMENVIRONMENTID PublicationID "tcm:X-Y-Z" -WebApplicationId WEBAPPID -RelativeUrl RELURL
```

all parameters looks good to me in my actual script, except the Last one: **RelativeUrl**

I don't understand what it points to and what should be its value for a:

- Single Language web Application
- Multi language web application

Here is what SDL doc has to say:

> RELURL is the relative URL from the web application context to the mapped location. If the mapped location is the root, omit this parameter.

What does: **mapped location** in above definition is referring to ?

For a Multilanguage website, should I have the RelativeUrl parameter set to "en", "es", "de" for each of the languages. ?

The multilingual publications in CMS have their Publication URL set to "en", "es"... Does **RelativeUrl** refers to these URLs set in CMS  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your question:

Q1: For a Multilanguage website, should I have the RelativeUrl parameter set to "en", "es", "de" for each of the languages. ?

**A1: Yes**

Example:

```
Add-TtmMapping -Id MAPPINGID -CmEnvironmentId CMENVIRONMENTID PublicationID "tcm:0-8-1" -WebApplicationId WEBAPPID -RelativeUrl en

Add-TtmMapping -Id MAPPINGID -CmEnvironmentId CMENVIRONMENTID PublicationID "tcm:0-9-1" -WebApplicationId WEBAPPID -RelativeUrl es
```

Q2: The multilingual publications in CMS have their Publication URL set to "en", "es"... Does RelativeUrl refer to these URLs set in CMS?

**A2: Yes**

[image]
[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Generally speaking, those answers are correct, although the use of so-called *Context-relative Publication URLs* is recommended. For some background info, see this classical Q&A: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14247/web-application-vs-web-site-in-topology-manager