# Understanding topology management

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager

I am learning topology concepts of SDL web 8.5. In the [SDL docs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-FAA9A349-213B-4892-B5AD-8D0D031A5AC8&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-8C66DDC4-99B1-483F-847B-B87AEE7EAB0C.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-FAA9A349-213B-4892-B5AD-8D0D031A5AC8), there is good information about different terminologies and concepts used in topology management. There is also and [example analogy](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-AEA866D1-94AF-4012-A45A-98FD0977FDAD&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-8C66DDC4-99B1-483F-847B-B87AEE7EAB0C.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-AEA866D1-94AF-4012-A45A-98FD0977FDAD) used to explain the concepts of topology management.

I am looking for an another example to enhance my understanding.

For example, I have 2 publication corresponding to 2 different locale EN and FR

Suppose I use http://xyz-training.com as my base URL and I need to host them to STG and LIVE CD environments.

Can someone explain me below concepts of with respect to the above example, please?

- Business Type
- Target Type
- Topology Type
- Purpose

I would like to know what is the correct way to create a website, web apps and how websites are mapped to Target Type?

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

In your example you mention one base URL (corresponds to Website in TTM terminology), but you mention two CD Environments: STG and LIVE.

These two CD Environments should have distinct Websites (base URLs). Furthermore, each Website has at least one WebApplication (often only a root WebApp, so that the URL of the WebApp is the same as the base URL of the Website).

Now, these two CD Environments belong together and they both serve a distinct purpose: one is for Staging and one for Live. These are the CD Environment Purposes.

The fact that they belong together means that they form a CD Topology and the Topology Type defines that the CD Topology consists of two environments: one with purpose Staging and one with purpose Live.

That outlines what your Topology Manager configuration looks like. Now, let’s look at Content Manager.

To be able to publish to your CD Topology, you will need to define a Business Process Type in Content Manager. This Business Process Type has an associated Topology Type in Topology Manager. It will also contain Target Types associated with the CD Environment Purposes of the Topology Type.

You associate the Publications you want to publish from with the Business Process Type.

Now, if you publish, you will see the two Target Types (or CD Environment Purposes, if you wish). However, if you would try to publish to any of those Target Types, you will see that nothing is resolved. That is because you haven’t defined any Mappings yet.

Finally, open the Publication properties and go to the Publishing tab. You will see the Target Types / Purposes listed there again and you can map each to a Web Application (represented by its URL) in Topology Manager. Optionally, you can specify a path for the Mapping (Relative URL in TTM Terminology). This Relative URL is appended to the Web Application’s URL.

In your case, you have two Publications (EN and FR) which both map to the same Website/WebApp (for the same Target Type). This is only possible if the Mappings have distinct Relative URLs, e.g. `en` and `fr`. As a result, the Mappings’ Primary URLs will look like `http://xyz-training.com/en` and `http://xyz-training.com/fr`.

You can also use the `Add-TtmMapping` PowerShell cmdlet to create Mappings or the `Get-TtmMapping` cmdlet to get an overview of all your Mappings.

Comment: For more details about Websites, Web Applications, Mappings and URLs, see: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14247/web-application-vs-web-site-in-topology-manager

Comment: great, thanks Rick. I will go through it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The Topology subject can be, and is, complicated, especially for someone who is new to it. The best way to learn it is to simply play around with it and try to "feel" how the concepts relate to each other.

Now there are a lot of resource, blogs, etc. out there, but I find the following one very useful. If you have earlier experience with Tridion, then this video [Topology Manager: How and Why](https://vimeo.com/175950249) does a very good job explaining how the old publishing model fits into the new one. Now do note that there are some differences (like the multiple "destinations") which were introduced in later versions of Tridion (the video is about Web 8), but for the most part all the Topology entities have remained the same. Besides explaining the old/new publishing models in comparison, it also explains all the TTM concepts, to some extent.

Comment: And there’s quite a bit of useful Q&A about Topology Manager here on Stack Exchange: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology-manager

Comment: great, thanks Atila and Rick. I will go through it in detail.

Comment: Hi Atila Sos, that's a great reference. TM makes lot of sense now. Thank you! :)

Comment: As @BartK once explained, _complicated_ doesn't necessarily mean hard just as simple doesn't necessarily mean "easy." ;-)